# How to add classpath resource in application.yml file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

With spring-boot, in case of application.properties file there is provision to specify classpath in value.

`app.templates = classpath:app\mock-templates`

How to specify same thing inside application.yml?

When specified like this, value read is not correct -

```
app:
  templates : 'classpath:app\mock-templates'
```

Value injection -

```
@Value("${app.templates}")
private String templateLocation; 
// value injected is "classpath:app\mock-templates", it should be <absolute-path>\app\mock-templates
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the single quotes in yml file

Comment: I removed quotes but result that spring is producing is still same. And I want it to be replaced by actual path for test.

Comment: so you want to directly give the path in yml file instead? if so you can give the path like C:/tmp/path ..

Comment: If I hardcode to any external path, test will fail during continuous integration. If I point to resource folder test can always refer to what is provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just check that no matter if you use `.properties` or `.yaml` file you will have always `classpath:app\mock-templates` as an injected property value. And that's ok. Spring does not complete `classpath:` prefix to the real path in a time of reading from properties. That will be done next by [ClassPathResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-implementations-classpathresource).

P.S. I think quotest also don't make any sense here.

Comment: In that case what will be ideal way if I want "classpath:" to be actual path. This is true for tests only. In main-application values is injected to external path so that works, but test can not refer to that external path, it needs to refer to resources directory.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same issue and there is a way to solve this. I tried using `classpath` but it does not work. Then I used this way

```
app:
  templates: "${PWD}/your/resources/dir/location"
```

In your `application.yml` file. It works for me just make sure your `PWD` will come from the path where your test are running. If you are using `git hooks` for running tests then mostly it's run from project root dir.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get this working by mentioning
`src/test/resources/<file_name>` in application.yml

```
  truststore: src/test/resources/trust.jks
```